# First link not working in responsive grid

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

Hello and thanks in advance.  I'm not a programmer but I have to use HTML in my job.  Backstory: This is for a learning management system, the links go to internal pages within the system.
The first link is not working, even when I switch say the last line with the first line the first line link doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<title>How to Video Series</title>
<style>
.grid { 
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
grid-gap: 20px;
align-items: stretch;
}
.grid img {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
max-width: 100%;
}
</style>

<main class="grid">

<div class="item">
<img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-IntroToSeries.jpg"><a 
href="https://..."></a>

<img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-AccessPFTranscript.jpg"> 
</a><a href="https://..."></a>

<img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo- 
InitialSetupAndAssignments.jpg"></a><a href="https://..."></a>

<img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-IDP_OJT.jpg"></a><a 
href="https://..."></a>

<img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo- 
NavigateKUODAnd101(PFVersion).jpg"></a><a href="https://..."></a>

<img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-IDP_KB.jpg"></a><a 
href='https://..."></a>

<img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-IDP_CurriculumReport.jpg"> 
</a><a href="https://..."></a>
</div>  
</main>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The link 404's or it isn't clickable?

Comment: You also have 13 closing `a` tags and only 7 opening `a` tags

Comment: It isn't clickable. The Learning Management System vendor is Cornerstone and it adds closing tags where I didn't originally place them.  Like before the <a href=...>

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of programming! There's several issues here, outlined below.

1. Your `<a>` tags aren't actually enclosing the content you want clicked. We have to wrap `<a>` *around* that we want clickable, `<a href="#"><p>Like this!</p></a>` and `<p>Not like this</p><a href="#"></a>`
2. There are several areas where a string is not being closed. `<img src="this/is/an/example ></img>`
3. There are more closing tags than there are ones that open. We'll just clean those up.
4. There are instances where a new line is inserted mid-string of an `img`'s `src` attribute. Don't start new lines just for human formatting with `src` attributes.
5. Some single quotes `'` are mixed with double quotes `"` when wrapped around strings. Be sure to be diligent in making sure those are the same.

Keep in mind I can't test the image sources because you're linking them locally. After that, your final code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>How to Video Series</title>
<style>
  .grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
  }
  .grid img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px  rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  max-width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<main class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="https://..."></a>
      <img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-IntroToSeries.jpg">
    </a>

    <a href="https://...">
      <img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-AccessPFTranscript.jpg"> 
    </a>

    <a href="https://...">
      <img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-">
    </a>

    <a href="https://...">
      <img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-IDP_OJT.jpg">
    </a>
    <a href="https://...">
      <img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-NavigateKUODAnd101(PFVersion).jpg">
    </a>

    <a href="https://...">
      <img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-IDP_KB.jpg">
    </a>

    <a href="https://..."></a>
      <img alt="" src="/clientimg/ku/welcome/How%20to%20Videos/THUMBNAIL-HowTo-IDP_CurriculumReport.jpg"> 
    </a>
  </div>  
</main>
```

Good luck!

Comment: That helped, it works now!  I see the errors you pointed out and followed your structure. Thanks Brann!!

Comment: No problem Chief, glad it worked! Don't forget to submit it as an answer! 